# Build input element and variations of them on the fly depending on user choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to build a interface where users can select options from a SELECT element and then based on the choice they made I should add elements on the fly. For example suppose that I have a select in this way:

```
<select required="required" name="product_variation[variation]" id="product_variation_variation">
    <option value="1">Size</option>
    <option value="2">Color</option>
    <option value="3">Size & Color</option>
</select>
```

So if user pick the first choice then I should show them three INPUT to them to allow write the value the quantity and the price for the product with this variation, the same happen for the second choice but for the third if you notice there are two options "Size & Color" then in this case I should generate as many INPUT as options are in this case:

```
size: XL
size: L
size: M
color: Red
```

In this case I should show 3 INPUT variations in this way:

```
INPUT1: size: XL color: Red 
INPUT2: size: L color: Red
INPUT3: size: M color: Red
```

Can any help me with this piece of code? So far I only have the part where I pick the selected value from the main SELECT element:

```
$("#product_create").on("change", "#product_variation_variation", function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var selected_item = that.find(":selected").val();

    if (selected_item === 1) {
        // build inputs for first option
    }   
});
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, I made a mockups to show yours what I need is more complex than your believe at least for me. See image below:

[image: Flow]

Now based on the image when users check "Has variations?" I show the select (just below the checkbox in the image) this is easy and I have done already. Now depending on what user pick from the select I should write "on the fly" some input elements. Basically for first time should be only one line meaning

```
"Enter value for size 1" | "Enter price for size 1" | "Enter qty (quantity) for size 1"
```

now if you notice there is a button just beside to add more rows based on the previous selection so if user click the button then should have:

```
"Enter value for size 1" | "Enter price for size 1" | "Enter qty (quantity) for size 1"
"Enter value for size 2" | "Enter price for size 2" | "Enter qty (quantity) for size 2"
```

And so on each time I click the "Add size" button. The same flow should happen if user pick color.

Now here is the hard part, if user picks "Size and Color" as you see in the image first I should ask user for Size values and then Color values, and after I should made variations based on those values as shows in the image at the end

This is what I want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jquery append or prepend to create elements.
Append

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Prepend

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/NWWAG/

```
 $("#product_create").on("change", "#product_variation_variation", function() {
        var that = $(this);
        var selected_item = that.find(":selected").val();

        if (selected_item === 1) {
            $(".element").append('<input type="text" id="new-id" />'); //Appends
            $(".element").prepend('<input type="text" id="new-id" />'); //Appends
        }   
    });
```

Comment: Hi, take a look at my edition is more complex than that but anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

is that what you are looking for?

```
var $select = $("#product_variation_variation");
$select.on("change", function() {
    var that = $(this),
        selected_item = that.val();

    if (selected_item === 1 || selected_item == 2) {
       insertInputs();
    }   
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/NWWAG/1/

I hope it helps and give you an idea of what you want to create.

thanks.